# Numerical integral in complex polar coordinates

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages, complex

`point = {m -> -3, \[Nu] -> -0.2}`

```
((r^(I \[Nu]) Cos[\[Theta] - \[Phi]] (Log[r/(1 + r^2 + 2 r Cos[\[Theta]])] -        Log[\[Rho]/(   1 + \[Rho]^2 + 2 \[Rho] Cos[\[Phi]])]) (Cos[\[Theta] +          m \[Theta] + \[Phi]] + I Sin[\[Theta] + m \[Theta] + \[Phi]]))/(  4 \[Pi]^2 (-E^(I \[Phi]) r +   E^(I \[Theta]) \[Rho]) (E^(I \[Theta]) r - E^(I \[Phi]) \[Rho])) /. point) //   NIntegrate[#, {r,0, +\[Infinity]}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {\[Rho],      0, +\[Infinity]}, {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] &
```

which is
[image]

When I do it in the comand line (typing "wolfram" in ubuntu linux and then insert the comand shown here) ,

it reports 2 errors

[image]

I guess maybe it is because there is a factor $r^{i \nu}\equiv \exp(i \nu \log(r))$ and when r becomes large, it oscillates wildly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Many Thanks!

Here is a unpolarized version:

```
NIntegrate[-1/8*((zb*zp + z*zpb)*(Log[(z*zb)/((1 + z)^2*(1 + zb)^2)]/2 - Log[(zp*zpb)/((1 + zp)^2*(1 + zpb)^2)]/2))/(Pi^2*z*(z/zb)^(3/2)*zb*(z*zb)^(I/10)*(z - zp)*zp*(zb - zpb)*zpb), {zp, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}, {zpb, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}, {zb, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
```

[image]

where `z=r Exp[I [Theta]] zp=[Rho] Exp[I [Phi]]`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the first term of the series expansion `point = {m -> -3, \[Nu] -> -1/5}

a = ((r^(I \[Nu]) Cos[\[Theta] - \[Phi]] (Log[
          r/(1 + r^2 + 2 r Cos[\[Theta]])] - 
         Log[\[Rho]/(1 + \[Rho]^2 + 
             2 \[Rho] Cos[\[Phi]])]) (Cos[\[Theta] + 
           m \[Theta] + \[Phi]] + 
         I Sin[\[Theta] + 
            m \[Theta] + \[Phi]]))/(4 \[Pi]^2 (-E^(I \[Phi]) r + 
         E^(I \[Theta]) \[Rho]) (E^(I \[Theta]) r - 
         E^(I \[Phi]) \[Rho])) /. point);`

Comment: `Normal[Series[
  Normal[Series[a, {r, \[Rho], 1}]], {\[Theta], \[Phi], 1}]]`, i.e. `(E^(-2 I \[Phi]) (r - \[Rho]) \[Rho]^(-3 - I/
  5) (-1 + \[Rho]^2) (Cos[\[Phi]] - 
   I Sin[\[Phi]]))/(4 \[Pi]^2 (\[Theta] - \[Phi])^2 (1 + \[Rho]^2 + 
   2 \[Rho] Cos[\[Phi]]))` shows a non-integratable singularity l`\[Theta] == \[Phi]`

Comment: But the Mathematica can still return a  result: 0.228957 - 0.0229808 I.

Comment: I have added the non-polarized version of this integral. Is it still non-integrable?